# Having trouble with multiple variables using read in a while loop

Tags: bash, variables, while-loop, inotify, ifs

Still learning and I'm getting lost with IFS=

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -m -r --excludei '(.txt$|.old$|.swp$|.swx$|.swpx$|.zip$)' /path/to/watch -e create |
    while read path action file; do
        cd $path
        USER="$(stat -c %U $file)"
        echo "To: User <user@domain.com>
CC: Support <user@domain.com>
From: $USER <user@domain.com>
Subject: $USER has Uploaded a new File

The user '$USER' uploaded the file '$file' to '$path'" >  /mnt/remote/ian/temp2.txt
    cat /path/to/temp/file.txt | ssmtp list@domain.com
    rm /path/to/temp/file.txt
done
```

This was my first ever script and it works great as long as there are no spaces in the the file names that get uploaded. I've read some scripts that use IFS= 'whatever' to define the field separators but I don't want to mess around with this while it's in production; it works, but it annoys me when I can't get the username of the user who uploaded the file. Please give me a hint.

Comment: Crossposting: http://serverfault.com/q/679424/234750

Comment: Since inotifywait's format strings don't support `\0` -- the only character which can't legally exist in a filename -- there literally *isn't* a 100%-reliable solution possible.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that's what I was scared of...

Comment: BTW, note how I'm using double-quotes around any expansion of `"$file"` or `"$path"`? That's essential to avoid bugs; http://shellcheck.net/ will point out any places where you're skipping it.

Comment: Actually -- I was wrong! Thinking about it more, you can safely use `//` as a delimiter; I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: Well... not as right as I was hoping for. You can use `//` as a delimiter, but only it's only easy to do safely when not using inotifywait in `-m` mode; lots of corner cases otherwise.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, I really appreciate your assistance here, my head is sore from banging it on my desk...

Comment: BTW, are you sure you want `create` (flagging when a file is created, but not necessarily when content is *done* being written to it), as opposed to `close_write`?

Comment: BTW -- don't use all-upper-case `USER`; that's an environment variable used for other things. Use `user` to avoid conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken by an attacker who knows your implementation and wants to spoof arbitrary data (by creating filenames with newlines), but it's a rough first draft:

```
while IFS= read -r -d $'\n' path && IFS= read -r -d $'\n' file; do
    user=$(stat -c %U "$file")
    printf 'File %q created by %q in %q\n' "$file" "$user" "$path"
done < <(inotifywait --format $'%w\n%f\n' ~/tmp -r -e create)
```

I'd strongly suggest filing a ticket with upstream inotifytools requesting the ability use `\0` in format strings.

---

Incidentally, this has already been brought up on the inotify-tools mailing list, where [Stephane Chazelas offered a workaround](http://sourceforge.net/p/inotify-tools/mailman/message/32195400/):

```
nl="
"
inotifywait --syslog -e close_write -mr /tmp --format '%f///' |
  while IFS= read -r file; do
    while :; do
      case $file in
        (*///) file=${file%///}; break
      esac
      IFS= read -r extra || exit
      file=$file$nl$extra
    done

    something with "$file"

  done
```